# Trouble with this.setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a grid of buttons with options that I want to be able to select. At first, all values are set at `false`. But there's a problem, every time I press a button for the first time, the value is still `false`, the second time it's `false` again (which is ok) and the third time is where the button is now set to `true`. I want to be able to set the value at `true` on the first ever time the button is pressed.

```
const {
    // This value is 'false' at first
    isArtAndCulture
} = stateController;

const [isAaC, setIsArtAndCulture] = useState(false);

...

<Block style={{ flex: 0.85, marginRight: 5 }}>
  <TouchableOpacity
    style={{
      height: 44,
      borderRadius: 5,
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
      backgroundColor: isAaC ? theme.colors.EventSection : theme.colors.Grey
    }}
    onPress={() => {
      setIsArtAndCulture(!isAaC);
      // Supposedly the value must be 'true' now, but when I print the 'isArtAndCulture' value,
      // it stays 'false' until the third button press.
      saveInState({ isArtAndCulture: isAaC });
      console.log(isArtAndCulture);
    }}
  >
    <Text
      profile
      text="Arte y Cultura"
      style={{
        fontFamily: theme.fonts.Bold,
        color: isAaC ? theme.colors.White : theme.colors.Black
      }}
    />
  </TouchableOpacity>
</Block>

saveInState = state => {
  this.setState(state);
}
```

Comment: Hey man, `this.setState` is used in class components and it looks like you're using functional components. Will need more code to see what you're trying to do exactly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately)

Comment: If it doesn't answer your question, we'll definitely need an [mcve] as the code shown right now is not enough (not even valid).

Answer (score 0):

As you are using

```
const [isAaC, setIsArtAndCulture] = useState(false);
```

You can change the state of `isAaC` via `setIsArtAndCulture`,

and if you are using `useState`, that means you are using the `functional component` so you can't use `this.` , you can use `this.setState` inside `class component` only

Change this :

```
saveInState = state => {
  this.setState(state);
}
```

To :

```
saveInState = (val) => {
   setIsArtAndCulture(val)
}
```

---

Do run the code snippet, Hope that will clear your doubts :

```js
const { useState } = React;

const App = () => {

  const [isAaC, setIsArtAndCulture] = useState(false);

  const saveInState = (val) => {
    setIsArtAndCulture(val);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      Current Val :  {isAaC ? "True" : "False"}
      <br/>
      <button onClick={() => saveInState(true)}>Make True</button>
      <button onClick={() => saveInState(false)}>Make False</button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('react-root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react-root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the previous state instead of directly inverting the variable `isAaC` like this:

```js
      setIsArtAndCulture((prevState) => !prevState);
```